# merging tables in mysql with month bases

Tags: php, mysql

i have 4 mysql tables , with different date field and there are no common column. i want to get sum of values in each table and combine all values in one table in monthly bases 
sample:

```
A_amt   A_vat   A_date
100     15  2018-01-15
50     6    2018-02-15


B_amt   B_vat   B_date
800   20    2018-03-15
40     9    2018-03-15


C_amt   C_vat   C_date
400    12   2018-01-15
90     6    2018-02-15


D_amt   D_vat   D_date
150     18    2018-01-15
10      4     2018-02-15
650     8     2018-05-15
```

i want the result like this:

[image]

```
>  select monthname(t.the_date )
>     , sum(t1.amt) as iamt
>     , sum(t1.vat) as ivat
>     , SUM(t2.amount) as amt
>     , sum(t2.vat) as vat 
>     , sum(t3.payment) as vamt
>     , sum(t3.vat) as vvat
>     , sum(t4.paid) as camt
>     , sum(t4.vat_amount) as nvat     from(   select indate as the_date   from invoice   union    select edate   from expense_details   union   
> select pdate   from vendor_payment   union    select paid_date   from
> vat ) t   left join invoice t1 on t.the_date  = t1.indate   left join
> expense_details t2 on t.the_date  = t2.edate   left join
> vendor_payment t3 on t.the_date  = t3.pdate   left join vat t4 on
> t.the_date  = t4.paid_date   group by monthname(t.the_date )
```

Comment: Please add code snippets of what you have tried and where you experience difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union for get the distinct date from all the 4 tables, left join for join the tables  and group by for sum

```
  select monthname(t.the_date )
    , sum(t1.A_amt)
    , sum(t1.A_vat)
    , sum(t2.B_amt)
    , sum(t2.B_vat) 
    , sum(t3.C_amt)
    , sum(t3.C_vat)
    , sum(t4.D_amt)
    , sum(t4.D_vat)  
  from(
  select A_date as the_date
  from table1
  union 
  select B_date
  from table2
  select D_date
  from table3
  select D_date
  from table4 ) t
  left join table1 t1 on t.the_date  = t1.A_date
  left join table2 t2 on t.the_date  = t2.B_date
  left join table3 t3 on t.the_date  = t3.C_date
  left join table4 t4 on t.the_date  = t4.D_date
  group by monthname(t.the_date )
```

Comment: is it possible to do it with php array ?

Comment: what do you mean with "its not working.." .. you have error .. ? .. wrong result.   ? .. expalin better